# Is this code written in Pl/Sql, and if not, then what language is it?

Tags: plsql, avaloq-script

I have encountered this code... Is this Pl/Sql? What do you think it is?

```
[Script 1.0]

    script package up is
    import native def_1;

     procedure p(

     i_g text
     )
     is

     l_txt text;
     begin



      with mem_m(idx) as msg do
        with book_aud(evt_id) as book do
          book.upd_pkt(
          evt_nr => i__nr
          ,ref_nr => msg.h.id
          ,account_nr => msg.h.id
          ,status => '1'
         );
        end with;
      end with;

     end p;
```

I am surprised by import and end with;

It is not the full code. It is reduced version of it.
It also contained familiar elements such as:

```
   c_max constant number := 95;
    c_VE_BA constant text := 'A07000'; 
    -- comment

     if i_mt is null then
     return rpad('/',16);
     else
     if i_id = zconst_.c_JPY then
     l_fmt := '9999999999999999';
     else
     l_fmt := '9999999999999D99';
     end if;
     end if;

case i_typ_id
 when def_typ.contr then
 l_zuonr := zfx2.c_avqt;
 when def_typ.fx then
 l_zuonr := zfx2.c_avqd;
 when def_typ.fxswap then
 l_zuonr := zfx2.c_avqd;
 when def_typ.forex then
 l_zuonr := zfx2.c_avqd;
 when def_typ.xfer then
 l_zuonr := zfx2.c_avqd;
 when def_typ.intr then
 l_zuonr := zfx2.c_avqt;
 else
 assert(false,'Meta Typ');
 end case;
```

It looks like an extension of Pl/Sql.
Based on the responses and my own research, I guess it is Avaloq+PL/Sql.
I contacted Avaloq,I am still waiting for official answer.

Comment: This doesn't look like PL/SQL to me.  The only things in common with PL/SQL that I see here is the "begin"

Comment: I cannot link it. I extracted what I deemed appropriate.

Comment: Will you mark the answer as accepted when you hear back? :)

Comment: I could but I did not get a reply from the official source.
Though I guess there is 90% chance that you are right.

Comment: I think this not Plsql. If you try to compile this with TOAD (with "create or Replace procedure p(....)...", it fails in a compilation error : "syntax Error" on the line "with mem_m(idx) as msg do....".

Answer (score 11):

It looks like [Avaloq](http://www.avaloq.ch/?l=en) Script, used by (ahem) Swiss banks, and while there is very little about it online, I found a [grammar](http://www.koders.com/noncode/fidCFFC9F3458D1BA0D75AE5EF624CBF55C049D906D.aspx?s=IContextManager) which perfectly matches the terms in your samples.

> Avaloq Script, the Avaloq Banking
>   System's script language, facilitates
>   entering specific business logic. The
>   structure of the data that can be
>   accessed through Avaloq Script is
>   defined in a DDIC (Data Dictionary),
>   making it unnecessary to know the data
>   storage structure.

Answer (score 6):

yes it is avaloq script. its some kind of pl/sql pre compiler, you should be able to find a package called s#up where the real pl/sql code resides.

Answer (score 6):

It definitely is Avaloq Script. The code snippet is a script package that Avaloq compiler compiles into PL/SQL. The point of Avaloq Script is to disallow direct database access and make the customizer of the Avaloq product to use the Avaloq API instead. The API is the Avaloq script language and a whole array of other ways like setting up rule tables to be loaded or special syntax to define forms, reports, workflows etc. often allowing snippets of Avaloq script within that other kind of sources.

Avaloq script has many PL/SQL elements but also some VB language concepts can be found. Here are some comments in the code to give some idea what the code means.

```
[Script 1.0]                      -- Have not seen other than 1.0 version

script package up is              -- The PL/SQL package name is going to be s#up
import native def_1;              -- import native means a PL/SQL package named 
                                  -- def_1 can be used, without native it is
                                  -- another Avaloq script package

 procedure p(                     -- declares a procedure with the name "p"

 i_g text                         -- input variable i_g defined text. 
                                  -- in PL/SQL this becomes a VARCHAR2
 )
 is

 l_txt text;                      -- local variable VARCHAR2(4000) in PL/SQL
 begin



  with mem_m(idx) as msg do       -- mem_m is a DDIC (Data Dictionary)
                                  -- It actually is a kind of "class" with
                                  -- fields and methods
                                  -- "with" is like in VB to avoid writing
                                  -- mem_m(idx) all the time e.g. mem_m(idx).h.id
    with book_aud(evt_id) as book do  -- book_aud is another DDIC that it is not
                                      -- prefixed with mem implies this is not a
                                      -- in memory structure but direct access
                                      -- to a Oracle table book_aud with index
                                      -- evt_id which looks undefined to me and 
                                      -- should bring a compiler error
      book.upd_pkt(                   --  method call in the book_aud DDIC
      evt_nr => i__nr                 -- like in PL/SQL named parameters
      ,ref_nr => msg.h.id
      ,account_nr => msg.h.id
      ,status => '1'
     );
    end with;
  end with;

 end p;
```

I could also comment on the other code snippet above but I think you already get out the general concept. Neither mem_m nor book_aud is a known DDIC in the Avaloq version I am working with, wonder where you got it from. Since your post is many years old I suppose this was a very old Avaloq release.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure that isn't [PL/SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/SQL).

I know this doesn't directly answer your question but I might suggest that you go though the list [here](http://www.ntecs.de/old-hp/uu9r/lang/html/lang.en.html). It *might* be listed in here. There are several examples of programs in different programming languages. **It may be hard to 100% identify** the language unless someone happens to recognize it and finds a "finger print" to prove the language... Do you have more examples you could post?

http://www.ntecs.de/old-hp/uu9r/lang/html/lang.en.html

I don't think that is a functional language. Knowing this might help narrow your search.

Comment: Avaloq Script is not on that list :)

Comment: I didn't create the list. Just suggesting a method to identify the language.

Answer (score 0):

The only language I can think of offhand that has "`with...end with`" syntax is visual basic. Could this be some scripting form of VB?